# How to resize DIV to match the screen size:

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML code which is the "red" box in the screenshot:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <div style="position: relative; left: 295px; top: 43px; height: 89%; width: 76%; background-color: #FF0000; overflow: auto;">
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        HERE IT IS<br>
        <span style="float: right;">TEST</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot for full desktop view ( you can see the `**TEST**` text on the bottom right ):

[image]

When I restored the window and it became a little smaller it looked like this: ( can't see the `**TEST**` text anymore and there is no scrollbar ):

[image]

As a test I looked at a mobile browser and it looks like this:

[image]

I am baffled as to how to make the red box so that if the contents are going beyond the screen toward the bottom, there is a vertical scroll bar, if the contents are going beyond the screen toward the right, there is a horizontal scroll bar, if both bottom and right, there should be two scroll bars. How do I achieve that?

Here is the code for the left navigation:

```
#leftNav {
    width: 275px;
    height: 412px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 10px;
    top: 42px;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url('../theImages/bg_80_b.png');
    text-align: left;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}
```

Comment: you need make your right column fluid (removing the width property)

Comment: From which DIV? both? or outer or inner?

Comment: Does setting the outer div to have `overflow: scroll;` fix your issue?

Comment: @Renson that will force a scroll bar even when one isn't needed; `overflow: auto;` should display one only when needed, so that isn't the issue.

Comment: I tried that and it does except it scrolls the entire page, but I am looking to add only on the DIV itself. I added the code for the navigation on the left, if it helps any.

Comment: @TylerH Woops, absolutely just glazed over the `overflow: auto;` in his code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding my comment: You have to make a fluid layout.

You have to avoid using % for your widths if you want a fluid layout. In others words, if you want your right column to be able to resize its self depending on the browser size, you have to remove any width property.


I don't have your full code so I made a simple fluid layout

## <strike>Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBtYb/)</strike>

## Check [JSFiddle (Updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/EBtYb/1/)

**Points to note:**

1. **Left Column is set to fixed width** and is floated to left

   ```
   #left {
       width: 200px;
       float: left;
   }
   ```
2. **Right columns has no width** but has a margin-left to push it to the right so it is next to the leftcolumn

   ```
   #right {
       margin-left:205px;
   }
   ```
3. **Clearing floats:** This is used to remove any float effects you have on any elements. Try experimenting "by removing" the `<div class="clear"></div>` to see whats happens, its easier than explaining

Comment: UPVOTED... PERFECT!!! It's working so far as I wanted to. :) But it looks like the "TEST" is out of the RED box

Comment: Where do you want me to add the CLEAR?

Comment: @SiKni8 Really? For me its in the red box. Have a look at the screenshot here: http://i.imgur.com/7xQJrrt.png What browser are you using? And Iv already added the clear in the jsFiddle, In my answer I meant trying removing them and see what happens

Comment: Yes really. It's kind of weird because I didn't even use the `clear: both` in my code and it's appearing in FF, Chrome and mobile browser as well.

Comment: @SiKni8 Oh I see what you mean, Im sorry, I forgot to update the jsFiddle! Click the link again and it should be in the redBox

Comment: Great. It's working. Quick workaround. What about if I want it to be 43 pixel from the bottom as well? I tried adding `margin-bottom: 43px` but it didn't work.

Comment: @SiKni8 want what to be 43px from the bottom? the "Test" or the red box?

Comment: @SiKni8 If you want a spacing of 43px between the bottom of the screen and the redbox, you can add `padding-bottom: 43px;` to the #container

Comment: By removing the red color it doesn't look like it's extending out. Everything is working as it should. Accepted your answer and also upvoted. THANKS!!!